# mvn tomcat:run terminates

Tags: java, maven-2, tomcat

When I call 'mvn tomcat:run' from my project, it starts up, then closes down immediately after a successful startup:

```
2011-01-18 13:02:10,636 INFO [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - FrameworkServlet 'myProject': initialization completed in 2010 ms
Jan 18, 2011 1:02:10 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jan 18, 2011 1:02:10 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4 minutes 26 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jan 18 13:02:10 CET 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 146M/274M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2011-01-18 13:02:11,645 INFO [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] - Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'myProjectWS-servlet': startup date [Tue Jan 18 13:02:06 CET 2011]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
```

Even running tomcat:run-war-only gives the same:

```
[INFO] Running war on http://localhost:8080/myProject
[INFO] Creating Tomcat server configuration at /Users/niklas/Documents/Eclipse/myProject/target/tomcat
Jan 18, 2011 1:19:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded start
INFO: Starting tomcat server
Jan 18, 2011 1:19:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29
Jan 18, 2011 1:19:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Set web app root system property: 'myProject-SNAPSHOT' = [/Users/niklas/Documents/Eclipse/myProject/target/myProject-4.1.0-SNAPSHOT/]
Jan 18, 2011 1:19:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing log4j from [/Users/niklas/Documents/Eclipse/myProject/target/myProject-4.1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties]
Jan 18, 2011 1:19:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 18, 2011 1:22:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'myProjectWS'
Jan 18, 2011 1:22:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'myProject'
Jan 18, 2011 1:22:08 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jan 18, 2011 1:22:08 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2 minutes 56 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jan 18 13:22:08 CET 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 120M/226M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Jan 18, 2011 1:22:09 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
```

Any idea what could cause it to shut down right away? No System.exit's anywhere in the code

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason is if [fork](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#fork) parameter is set to true.